# Как прочитать директорию на Vue + Vite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite

Приложение построено на Vue.js. Нужно, прочитать директорию и название файлов в ней.

Есть множество решений, но ни одно не получилось использовать, node не поддерживается конечно, FileSystem API тоже не особое хочет работать.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Как использовать Node во Vue приложении? Или есть какие-то аналоги решения?

Comment: Что значит "Не особо хочет работать"?

Comment: Это значит не работает )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vite поддерживает импорт нескольких модулей из файловой системы с помощью специальной функции: import.meta.glob

```
const modules = import.meta.glob('./dir/*.js')
```

Этот импорт будет преобразован в

```
// code produced by vite
const modules = {
  './dir/foo.js': () => import('./dir/foo.js'),
  './dir/bar.js': () => import('./dir/bar.js')
}
```

Затем вы можете перебирать ключи modules объекта для доступа к соответствующим модулям:

```
for (const path in modules) {
  modules[path]().then((mod) => {
    console.log(path, mod)
  })
}
```

Больше информации в документации vite - [Vite: глобальный импорт](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import)

Comment: Хороший ответ, хочу лишь добавить что есть еще `globEager`, который во время компиляции трансформирует указанные импорты в статичные `import x from "y"`, что позволяет избежать необходимость обходить объект с модулями. Но при этом, понятное дело, ни о каком code-splitting'е и tree-shaking'е речи не идет.